# Asp.net Html editor Extender: how to limit font size?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, htmleditorextender

How can I change a html editor extender's maximum allowed font size to 16px or '3' setting programmatically?  I searched web but couldnt find any parameters for this like :

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="zz" .... .... .. runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:HtmlEditorExtender MaxFontSize="16" ..... ..... runat="server"></asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Got this error as expected:

```
 Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditorExtender' does not have 
 a public property named 'MaxFontSize'.
```

Can this be done in Jquery or codebehind? This could be problematic when web pages are not designed for big fonts while control panel page allows big fonts automatically.

There are

```
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  ...
```

in the last stage of page(looking through chrome's "look at source" option) and I need to destroy things like these with value bigger than 3 or 4.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of a process to customize the Font Name list and Font Size list, but it requires a bit of coding.

Start with this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/htmleditor/how-do-i-use-the-html-editor-control-cs).

This will show you how to write your own HTMLEditor class that will inherit the default HTMLEditorExtender Class from AJAXControlToolkit.

Next you need to customize your toolbars. Start [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1499167.aspx).

Lastly, you will need to add FontName Options and Font Size Options to the DropDownLists. You will find some code to work with [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1652683.aspx?HTML%20Editor%20Font%20Names%20amp%20Sizes).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry this answer is useless as the htmlextender completely different from the old html editoe